# Axios Request Interceptors - Do Something on Request Completion

Tags: reactjs, axios

As per the bellow code, Axios request interceptors can be used to so something, before the request is sent or when there is an error in the request. Like wise, Is there a way to identify the request completion event as well with axios request interceptors (Not with response interceptors)?

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
        // Do something before request is sent
        return config;
      }, function (error) {
        // Do something with request error
        return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try with the request handler

```
const requestHandler = (request) => {
if (isHandlerEnabled(request)) {
//your code here
})
}
return request
}
// Add interceptors
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
request => requestHandler(request)
)
```

Reference link:- https://codepen.io/teroauralinna/pen/vPvKWe?editors=0010